# Set ColdFusion on Wheels cache to store in filesystem

Tags: caching, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In ColdFusion on Wheels, I am trying to find out ways to cache in the filesystem instead of memory.
How could I set this and specify the cache path in ColdFusion on Wheels?

I cannot find any related information about this in the documentation:

- http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/configuration-and-defaults
- http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/caching